# How to work with varargs (number of arguments) and reflection in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, reflection

I've got this method (in java):

```
public void insert(final MyCustomObject... obj)
```

I know the package name and the class name of `MyCustomObject` as well as the method name so I am using it during reflection (using Kotlin):

```
val myCustomObjectClass = Class.forName("${packageName}${className}")
val myCustomObject = myCustomObjectClass.getConstructor(String::class.java, Long::class.java)
val insertMethod = classContainingInsertMethod.getDeclaredMethod("insert", myCustomObjectClass)
```

the class `classContainingInsertMethod` was created earlier. Now, how could I invoke the method? I got an exception that there is no such method. I am aware of that because it is a number of args, not a single one.

I tried using `arrayOf(myCustomObjectClass)::class.java` but this gave me just another exception. Using `*myCustomObjectClass` didn't work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array
val varArg = Array.newInstance(myCustomObjectClass, 1)
val varArgClass = varArg::class.java
val myCustomObjectConstructor = myCustomObjectClass.getConstructor(String::class.java, Long::class.java)
val myCustomObjectElement = myCustomObjectConstructor.newInstance("", 0L)
Array.set(varArg, myCustomObjectElement, 0)
```

(here the size of array and number of `set` calls will correspond to the number arguments you want to pass in varargs) and then

```
val insertMethod = classContainingInsertMethod.getDeclaredMethod("insert", varArgClass)
insertMethod.invoke(instanceOfClassContainingInsertMethod, varArg)
```

Comment: Is the full class name `java.lang.reflect.Array.` needed here?

Comment: Just to clarify which `Array`. Of course you can import it as well.

Comment: That works! I would like to extend the question though. Should I always pass the actual numbers of parameters in `newInstance` method? In other words - I should always know how many arguments I would pass in the invoke. Am I right?

Comment: In `Array.newInstance`? No, it's just created to get a `Class` and the array itself is thrown away. Or maybe I misunderstand your question...

Comment: I mean, If use 0 as you shown here and then using invoke pass a series of arguments (let's say an array of 3 elements) won't be that error?

Comment: if this is just for creating an array class obj - that's great :D

Comment: Got this when invoked method: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: method XXX argument 1 has type com.example.app.MyCustomObject[], got java.lang.Object[]

this is how I invoke the method:

val myCustomObjectElement = myCustomObjectCons.newInstance(name, 0,, 0)
insertMethod.invoke(classContainingInsertMethod, arrayOf(myCustomObjectElement))

Comment: Ah right, then you _will_ need an array of as many elements as you'll pass and can reuse the instance created to get the `Class`, see the new code.

Comment: Also the first argument to `invoke` needs to be an instance of class containing `insert` (or `null` if it's static), not the class object `classContainingInsertMethod`.

Comment: this is the class which contains this method :P

Comment: i mean, I edited my code (changed names) and here is obviously an instance of that class, so that's not the problem

Comment: please check how I instantiate an object of myCustomClass in the previous comment. There is no adding such elements to the list in your answer. Can't invoke method passing a class type as an argument...

Comment: Because the `val myCustomObjectElement = myCustomObjectCons.newInstance(...)` is the same as in your comment.

Comment: Solved, didn't get what are number of sets. Just needed to know how to add items to the vararg. Cool, its working as intended now! Thanks mate